# Variable issue with my python guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm making a guessing game where you have the option of an easy medium and hard mode but when I adjusted my code so that the display changes from 100 to 1,000,000 I get an error saying:

```
File "C:/Users/Zach Hirschman/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/GuessGame.py", line 38, in main
    if guess > randomNumber:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'randomNumber' referenced before assignment
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```
"""
Zach Hirschman
12/20/2017
GuessGame.py

This program asks the user to guess a number
"""

import random

def main():
    difficulty = input("Enter a difficulty level: 'easy','medium', or 'hard' 
: ")
print("At any time, type 'hint' to get a hint")
if difficulty == "easy":
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,100)

elif difficulty == "medium":
    randumNumber = random.randint(1,10000)

elif difficulty == "hard":
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,1000000)

found = False

while not found:
    if difficulty == "easy":
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100"))

        if guess > randomNumber:
            print("Too high")
        elif guess == randomNumber:
            print("Thats correct!!")
            found = True
        else :
            print("Too Low")

    elif difficulty == "medium":
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10000"))

        if guess > randomNumber:
            print("Too high")
        elif guess == randomNumber:
            print("Thats correct!!")
            found = True
        else :
            print("Too Low")

    elif difficulty == "hard":
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 1000000"))
        if guess > randomNumber:
            print("Too high")
        elif guess == randomNumber:
            print("Thats correct!!")
            found = True
        else :
            print("Too Low")



x = input("would you like to play again? Type 'yes' or 'no': ")

if x == "yes":
    main()

else:
    print("See you later!")
main()
```

Comment: You should define `randomNumber` outside the `if`s. Such as putting `randomNumber = 0` before them. Then the `if`s just update the value

Comment: as the first line under `def main():` (or at least before you use `randomNumber`), put a default definition for `randomNumber`, i.e. `randomNumber = 0`

Comment: `randumNumber = random.randint(1,10000)` When difficulty is "medium", you're initializing the wrong variable name.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will make sure to do that.

Comment: Please make sure your code indentation here matches yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was just a scoping issue. For randomNumber variable to be available in the while loop, the while loop has to be within the same function that the variable is declared in (eg. main()): then they have the same "scope".

Initialising randomNumber before the `if` statements is not needed and will make no difference. That is usually done before `for` or `while` loops (as you did with `found = False`). randomNumber was not being initialised because it depended on "difficulty", which was out of scope.

Note that after defining it, the function has to be called by `main()`. In your code main() wasn't running, only the ifs/while parts were as they were written outside the function.

```
import random

def main():
    difficulty = input("Enter a difficulty level: 'easy','medium', or 'hard' : ")

    print("At any time, type 'hint' to get a hint")
    if difficulty == "easy":
        randomNumber = random.randint(1,100)

    elif difficulty == "medium":
        randomNumber = random.randint(1,10000)

    elif difficulty == "hard":
        randomNumber = random.randint(1,1000000)

    found = False

    while not found:
        if difficulty == "easy":
            guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100"))

            if guess > randomNumber:
                print("Too high")
            elif guess == randomNumber:
                print("Thats correct!!")
                found = True
            else :
                print("Too Low")

main()
```

The other options are:

- moving everything out of the function, which will work fine by gets complicated for longer programs
- adding a return value to main() and binding it to randomNumber. This would also require the same for the difficulty variable, so would be better to refactor into multiple smaller functions.

Finally, randomNumber had a typo - that didn't cause the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which simplifies a little your solution:

```
import random

difficulty_thresholds = {
    "easy" : 100,
    "medium" : 10000,
    "hard" : 1000000
    }

wants_to_continue = True
while wants_to_continue:
    difficulty = input("Enter a difficulty level: 'easy','medium', or 'hard': ")
    maximum_number = difficulty_thresholds.get(difficulty, 100)
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, maximum_number)

    found = False
    while not found:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and {}: ".format(maximum_number)))

        if guess > randomNumber:
            print("Too high")
        elif guess == randomNumber:
            print("That's correct!!!")
            found = True
        else:
            print("Too Low")

    do_we_continue = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'yes' or 'no': ")

    wants_to_continue = do_we_continue  == "yes"

print("See you later!")
```